# Google Calendar embeds - but won't respond

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed, google-calendar-api

I successfully embedded the Google Calendar IFRAME, however, without any JS error -- it won't respond to any of my clicks, nor display any events.

After double checking the calendar settings and googling this issue I'm finally without a clue as to how to resolve this. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using firebug (or equivalent) to see whether the events HTML is received? That could help put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the main problem is that the events are not showing in the embedded google calendar. I would suggest:

1. check the sharing settings on the calendar, make sure that it is shared properly and that all (or all you want) can see the events on it.
2. I found a couple of reports of similar problems (see 
   http://groups.google.com/group/google-calendar-help-publishers/browse_thread/thread/a2a4ce5d562b9a79/f633e16918b1ee8a and
   http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=4c718806cc8faa1e&hl=en) in which events stopped appearing for a certain month on a few calendars. There are some makeshift solutions in those posts (such as setting the events to be all day, or 1 minute long), but no real solution, I'm afraid.
3. to continue from 2, try adding events to other months (last month and next month, for example). If you find the problem to be specific for a certain month, maybe it will lead you in the right direction. At least you'll know you're not alone.
4. check what google's response to the embed url is (using FireBug for example). If I'm not mistaken, the events are added via JS, and are received in a JSON string. Check whether the events are received at all.

So, to sum it up, there's no definite solution, it seems, but try these directions, see if you can narrow it down. 
good luck.